# How to customize Horizontal dots plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, data-visualization, ggplotly

I want to plot customized Horizontal dots using my data and the code given [here](https://www.rebeccabarter.com/blog/2018-05-29_getting_fancy_ggplot2/)
data:

```
df <- data.frame (origin = c("A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J"),
              Percentage = c(23,16,32,71,3,60,15,21,44,60),
              rate = c(10,12,20,200,-25,12,13,90,-105,23),
              change = c(10,12,-5,12,6,8,0.5,-2,5,-2))
```

.

```
      origin Percentage rate change
1       A         23   10   10.0
2       B         16   12   12.0
3       C         32   20   -5.0
4       D         71  200   12.0
5       E          3  -25    6.0
6       F         60   12    8.0
7       G         15   13    0.5
8       H         21   90   -2.0
9       I         44 -105    5.0
10      J         60   23   -2.0
```

obs from 'origin' column need be put on y-axis. corresponding values in 'change' and 'rate' column must be presented/differentiated through in box instead of circles, for example values from 'change' column in  lightblue and values from 'rate' column in blue. In addition I want to add second vertical axis on right and put circles on it which size will be defined based on corresponding value in 'Percentage' column.

Output of code from the link:
[image]

Expected outcome (smth. like this:
[image]

Comment: Instead of making us read the whole article and infer which code you're using, can you just include it in the question (having the link as well for perspective is good).

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

First, reshaping so that both `rate` and `change` are in one column better supports ggplot's general preference towards "long" data.

```r
df2 <- reshape2::melt(df, id.vars = c("origin", "Percentage"))
```

(That can also be done using `pivot_wider`.)

The plot:

```r
ggplot(df2, aes(value, origin)) +
  geom_label(aes(label = value, fill = variable, color = variable)) +
  geom_point(aes(size = Percentage), x = max(df2$value) +
20, shape = 21) +
  scale_x_continuous(expand = expansion(add = c(15, 25))) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c(change="lightblue", rate="blue")) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c(change="black", rate="white")) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.border = element_blank(), panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor.x = element_blank()) +
  labs(x = NULL, y = NULL)
```

[image]

The legend and labels can be adjusted in the usual ggplot methods. Overlapping of labels is an issue with which you will need to contend.

Comment: How can I add the horizontal lines and remove grey background? I need to totally make this graph look like the I posted

Comment: `geom_hline`? `theme`?

Comment: See my edit, some changes and hints

Answer (score 0):

**Update** on OP request: See comments:

```
gg_dot +
  geom_text(aes(x = rate, y = origin, 
                label = paste0(round(rate, 1), "%")),
            col = "black") +
  geom_text(aes(x = change, y = origin, 
                label = paste0(round(change, 1), "%")),
            col = "white") +
  geom_text(aes(x = x, y = y, label = label, col = label),
            data.frame(x = c(40 - 1.1, 180 + 0.6), y = 11, 
                       label = c("change", "rate")), size = 6) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("#9DBEBB", "#468189"), guide = "none") +
  scale_y_discrete(expand = c(0.2, 0))
```

[image]

**First answer:**
Something like this?

```
library(tidyverse)
library(dslabs)

gg_dot <- df %>% 
  arrange(rate) %>%
  mutate(origin = fct_inorder(origin)) %>% 
  ggplot() +
  # remove axes and superfluous grids
  theme_classic() +
  theme(axis.title = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
        axis.line = element_blank()) +
  # add a dummy point for scaling purposes
  geom_point(aes(x = 12, y = origin), 
             size = 0, col = "white") +
  
  # add the horizontal discipline lines
  geom_hline(yintercept = 1:10, col = "grey80") +
  
  # add a point for each male success rate
  geom_point(aes(x = rate, y = origin), 
             size = 11, col = "#9DBEBB") +
  # add a point for each female success rate
  geom_point(aes(x = change, y = origin),
             size = 11, col = "#468189") 



gg_dot +
  geom_text(aes(x = rate, y = origin, 
                label = paste0(round(rate, 1))),
            col = "black") +
  geom_text(aes(x = change, y = origin, 
                label = paste0(round(change, 1))),
            col = "white") +
  geom_text(aes(x = x, y = y, label = label, col = label),
            data.frame(x = c(40 - 1.1, 180 + 0.6), y = 11, 
                       label = c("change", "rate")), size = 6) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("#9DBEBB", "#468189"), guide = "none") +
  scale_y_discrete(expand = c(0.2, 0))
```

[image]

Comment: How can I add %s within circle and right vertical axes?

Comment: honestly circles do not look great, can we smooth them as in original plot?

Comment: You are right, but now you know how to do it in general and with the mendtioned tutorial you should invest some efforts to adapt it for your data.

Comment: I have tried but still struggle to meet the expected output